# Convert RFC 822 date to valid Date for javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using a script calendar that when I choose a date, it convert it to a new format (yyyy-mm-dd)

It works in most browser but in Firefox and Opera, I get an invalid date format because the format i work with is RFC 822.

I'm looking for a way to convert this date format

example:

```
Thu Sep 08 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

and change it to

```
2011-09-08
```

Could that be done in javascript ?

**UPDATE**

Here's my code trying to replace the (EDT) to nothing

```
$(".taskDate").datepick({
          onSelect: function(selectedDate){
            selectedDate = selectedDate.replace(/ \(.+\)/, '');
            //alert(selectedDate);
            var newDate = new Date(selectedDate);
            $(".selectedDate").text(newDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+newDate.getDate());
            location.href="index.php?date="+newDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+newDate.getDate();
          }
        });
```

Now I get an error

```
selectedDate.replace is not a function
```

How come ?

**UPDATE 2**

Fixed it because it seems that it was an object and not a darn string.
Added

```
selectedDate = selectedDate.toString();
```

before the new Date();

Now it's working for all browsers...

Comment: 1.) You don't have to remove the `(EDT)`.  2.) if `replace` is not a function, `selectedDate` is not a string.

Comment: if it's not a string what it is then ?? Because if I alert the selectedDate the alert is Thu Sep 08 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)... so it must be a string

Comment: Added selectedDate.toString(); before to force it and it works now :S Next time i'll choose another datepicker darn it.

Comment: I think, it's a jQuery element. Using `alert` calls the `toString` method automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works in Firefox6, see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZnEw/).

```
var sOriginalDate = 'Thu Sep 08 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)';
var oDate = new Date(sOriginalDate);
var iMonth = oDate.getMonth() + 1;
var iDay = oDate.getDate();
var sNewDate = oDate.getFullYear() + '-'
    + (iMonth < 10 ? '0' : '') + iMonth + '-'
    + (iDay < 10 ? '0' : '') + iDay;
alert(sNewDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the date is RFC 822 you could parse it to a valid Date (the ending EDT does not affect the result):

```
var dateAsDateObject = new Date(Date.parse(dateInRFC822Format));
```

This will work with `dateInRFC822Format` equal to either `"Thu Sep 08 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"` or `"Thu Sep 08 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0400"`

Now you can get the info you require from dateAsDateObject:

- year: `dateAsDateObject.getFullYear()`
- month: `dateAsDateObject.getMonth()`
- day: `dateAsDateObject.getDay()`

**Note:** for formatting, if you don't mind using jqueryui you could also use the  `$.datepicker.formatDate()` method. E.g. `var stringRepresentation =  $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateAsDateObject);`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var mydate = new Date(originaldate);
mydate = mydate.getYear() + '-' + (mydate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + mydate.getDate();
```

Comment: Seems that new Date() with RFC 822 is deprecated and that why I have invalid date to Firefox and Opera. I need to convert that RFC 822 before calling the new Date function.

Comment: It's very close to the RFC 1123 format that *is* accepted e.g. "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT". What's generating your original format?

Comment: It the datepick (http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html?#events) onSelect function.

Comment: Could it be the damn (EDT) at the end that might not ba a valid string ?

Comment: @Bobby, `getYear` is deprecated as well. use `getFullYear`